# Can't install or update anything

Tags: 12.04

I tried to update using sudo apt-get update but the following error occured:

```
    elease  rename failed, Read-only file system (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_octave_stable_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release -> /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_octave_stable_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release).

    W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  rename failed, Read-only file system (/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release -> /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release).

    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  rename failed, Read-only file system (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release).

    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  rename failed, Read-only file system (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_transmissionbt_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release -> /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_transmissionbt_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release).

    W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release  rename failed, Read-only file system (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_Release -> /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_Release).

    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used   instead.
    W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
    E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
    E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following commands :

```
sudo -i

apt-get clean

cd /var/lib/apt

mv lists lists.old

mkdir -p lists/partial

apt-get clean

apt-get update
```

This will rename your "list" folder to "list.old" for backup purposes and then rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I typed  sudo -i    there is another error:
        sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/ansar/0: Read-only file system